# VM Virtualbox issues

Tags: server, virtualbox, vim

I am running Ubuntu server 16.04.2 and desktop 16.04.2 on Virtualbox and the desktop seems fine but the server is having a hard time starting network device and I cannot get the two OS's to talk to each other. Also when using Vim, cannot edit vsftpd.conf, says cannot write, even though I go in and remove # from write option.

Comment: You need to set the VM network to _internal_ to get them to communicate with each other. For the _write_ check the file permission.

Comment: vsftpd is a different story. There are many possibilities why you can not upload a file to the server. As George mentioned it could be a simple file permission problem or a vsftpd configuration issue or a ip-filter issue. Please describe what you have done in detail and the ftp client error message you received. Do you use iptables on server/client side ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there seems to be different issues. Let me state a solution to "I cannot get the two OS's to talk to each other"

One choice to let VirtualBox Guests communicate to each other is "Host-only Adapter" configuration. The default network is 192.168.56.0/255.255.255.0
How to use it with the VirtualBox GUI:
1) open the Settings for you Virtual Guest
2) click on "Network"
3) "Adapter 1" can be set to "Attached to: NAT" this is okay for internet access
4) choose tab "Adapter 2" and choose "Attached to: Host-only Adapter". Use "Name: vboxnet0"
5) click the okay button to setup your configuration to the guest.

You have to make sure that "vboxnet0" is setup in a proper way.
To do so you have to press "Ctr+G" or go to the Main-Menu "File" --> "Preferences"
Choose "Network" --> "Host-only Networks"
From here you should see "vboxnet0". If you double-click it opens a new window. Here you should see the ip 192.168.56.1 -- this is for you Host-System. Your VirtualBox Guest will get an address from DHCP. So click on the tab "DHCP Server" to check this. You can remember the range and configure later on a static 192.168.56.x address outside of this range.
After you started the guest system and do a console login you should see a new device with a 192.168.56.x IP address (ifconfig -a).
If so your configuration was successful.